# 3-way switch w/ dimmer

Tags: electrical

I have a 3-way switch in our dining room (just 2 switches) and have replaced the one we use the most with a 3-way w/ dimmer. The light turns on just fine, but will not dim.  I have installed a Lutron- Eco-dim dimmer (3-way)...  Need help as to why it won't dim.

Comment: Did you follow the dimmer instructions for wiring with a 3way switch?

Comment: You're not using a CFL, right? They're not dimmable (incandescent, halogen or most LED's are dimmable).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the Lutron Model number of the switch but most of the Lutron Maestro switches are not like conventional 3-way/4-way switches. They require a Lutron companion switch at the other 3-way location in order to operate properly. Check the instructions for multiple location installations. Make sure the circuits off when you change the other one,  hooking them up live can kill them, and they're not cheap.